# World War 1: Why did Italy not fight until 1915?

Tags: 20th-century, world-war-one, italy

Today I learnt history about World War 1 and I have a question that has been bothering me.

According to what I have studied, the Triple Alliance (1882-1915) was an alliance between Germany, Austria-Hungary, and Italy. And the term of the alliance is that if Italy was attacked by a power, Austria-Hungary and Germany would assist her. And likewise, if Austria-Hungary and Germany were attacked, Italy would assist them too.

How did Italy cancel the "agreement" in the Triple Alliance? I meant there were "fights" and "agreements in advance". Why did not Italy and how did it have the right not to participate into the WWI?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The core of the [Triple Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_Alliance_(1882)) was Germany and Austria-Hungary who promised to protect each other against attack by *any* third party. Italy was an "adjunct" member, who promised and was promised protection against attack only by France. But Italy "opted out" because Austria-Hungary had violated a clause in the treaty to consult with Italy before changing the status quo in the Balkans (Austria-Hungary did not do so before attacking Serbia.)

The Achilles heel of the alliance was that Italy and Austria-Hungary basically hated each other, perhaps even more than either hated France. Each feared "retaliation" by the other; Italy in Venice, Austria-Hungary in Tyrol.

Italy "got around" to joining the Allies in 1915 when they promised her Tyrol *and* Trieste as spoils of war. (Ironically, Germany and Austria-Hungary even offered her *South* Tyrol to rejoin them.)

Comment: That's a little thing called "diplomacy". When the high-falutin' treaties are being signed it's "All for one, and one for all!", but after the cannons start cannonading it's, "...and every man for himself!".

Comment: France declared war on Germany, not the other way around; and French troops entered Germany long before any German troops entered France.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Fixed end of first paragraph. Thanks for your help.